# $('#iframe').load() responds very late on production, though it is running well on development (local) environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

alert('loaded') fires very late on production. I couldn't figure out what is causing it to fire late on production.

Following is an excerpt from original code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function showIframe () {
        var html = '<iframe id="myIframe" src="https://calendly.com/.../15min"></iframe>';

        $("#testDiv").html(html);

          setTimeout(function () {
            $("#myIframe").load(function (e){
              alert('loaded');
          });

        }, 200);

      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <button onclick = 'showIframe()'>iFrame</button>
    <div id = 'content' style = 'width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: lemonchiffon;'></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The URL that I am loading in this iframe is an external URL (i.e. not related to my website).

Answer (score -1):

If you run the page under IE/Edge, it's common for the https site loading taking a long time. Google it you will find links about it. Other browsers should be OK.